# Geometry with vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V = 25i  + 15j  - 30k$. What angles does this vector make with the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes?

Can someone go all the way through and show me how this is done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The angle that $\def\V{{\bf V}}$ makes with the $x$-axis is the same as the angle it makes with the vector $\def\I{{\bf i}}\I = (1,0,0)$, which points the same way.

$$\def\vdot{{\cdot}}\V\vdot \I = |\V||\I|\cos\theta$$

where $\theta$ is the angle you want.

But $\V\vdot \I$ is just $25\cdot 1 + 15 \cdot 0 + -30\cdot 0 = 25$.

So the angle here is $$\theta =\cos^{-1} \frac{25}{|\V||\I|}.$$

Where $|\V| = \sqrt{25^2 + 15^2 + (-30)^2}$ and $|\I| = \sqrt{1^2+0^2+0^2}$.

Can you do the rest yourself?

Comment: To be honest I am trying to get ahead but I need come help. Can you show me how to find the rest of the components. Then I will interpret them to you to make sure i get exactly what you are doing?

Comment: No, I think you should try it yourself and if you get stuck, ask a question about the thing that is giving you difficulty.

Comment: Well I guess I'm trying to figure out what |V| is going to be.

Comment: I added that. Can you do it now?

Comment: Ok so it is the arccos then. To solve for j and k would I do the same thing in the denominator except just switch out the values in the numerator?

Comment: Well that is interesting because my computer doesn't seem to like that answer as far as cos theta is concerned.

Comment: Yup I plugged the first into my computer and it doesn't like the answer. I have no idea what is going on then.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter, $\cos^{-1}(\frac{5}{\sqrt{70}}) \sim 0.930274$ is in radian, do your computer want answer in degree $53.3007748^{\circ}$ instead?

Comment: @achille hui What did you get for the the y and z components in terms of degrees?

Answer (score 1):

The angle $\theta$ between the vectors $u,v$ can be found using $\cos \theta=\dfrac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|u\|\|v\|}$ where $\langle .,.\rangle$ is the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition). See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition).

Answer (score 1):

$V=5(5i+3j-6k)$, thus $V$ has the same direction as $5i+3j-6k$.

Unit (easy to handle) vectors with the directions of the axes are $1i+0j+0k$ for the $x$-axis, $0i+1j+0k$ for the $y$-axis, and $0i+0j+1k$ for the $z$-axis.

To find the angle between two vectors given their cartesian components, you can use the dot product.

$$a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos\theta.$$

In other words:

$$\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{a\cdot b}{|a||b|}\right)=\theta.$$